# Multiple videos not playing using <video> tag in different html using cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, html5-video

I have a scenario where I need to play multiple videos at the same time in different html.
I am able to play multiple videos in the same html but if I switch from one html to other then one of the videos in html stops and only one video is played at a time.

Below is my html code:

```
<video autoplay loop webkit-playsinline width="320" height="180">
<source src="images/page/welcome.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Same code is for both html files.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Siddharth_Vyas, did you find solution to your problem? I'm stuck in the same situation...